# Issue with cloudformation in target groups and ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use cloudformation to setup a ASG and I have a target group which I would like to associate with the ASG. The target group is created okay but when I go to attach it to the ASG I get an error message. I'd like to be able to attach this as I want a ALB in front of the ASG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, TargetGroupARNs value should be of type List. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-targetgrouparns